# Powerhell - WMI and Programs and Features do not necessarily correlate how can we get an accurate picture of all installed software?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get a full list of installed programs on a remote computer. It spits out a long list of programs installed.

how can we get an accurate picture of all installed software via WMI like Get-Package ?

btw,  We have mixed powershell 2, 3, 4, 5 versions.

```
Get-Package -ProviderName Programs

Name                           Version          Source    ProviderName
----                           -------          ------     ------
Operations-agent               12.15.005...                 Programs
LiveUpdate 3.3 (Symantec Co... 3.3.100.15                   Programs
Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2... 14.27.29016.0                Programs
Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 R... 14.12.25810.0                Programs
Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 R... 12.0.40660.0                 Programs
Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 R... 12.0.40660.0                 Programs
```

.....

```
$list = echo comp001 comp002 comp003
invoke-command $list { get-package }
```

Comment: `Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Product`?

Comment: First of all, what is an _installed_ program? If you create a folder at `C:\Program Files` and copy a binary to it, it will be a kind of _installed_ software, but it will not show up in any WMI lists, even if you have a shortcut on your desktop or in your start menu. So, how do you define installed software in your case? What about the software in your system root? What about user-specific software inside user profiles?

Comment: Already installed software inside OS. So not portable or user-specific software. Also , I can see it inside Add/Remove Programs.

Comment: @mklement0  I have updated my question. (invoke command)  but I want to do WMI method instead of Get-Package.

Comment: There are plenty of softwares that can be installed that show in Programs and Features list that are not installed with Windows Installer. If you are looking to enumerate Programs and Features, then just read the registry and enumerate Programs and Features. (This won't enumerate per-user softwares, though. That's a separate issue.)

Comment: Wouldn't reading the registry in `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` and `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` give you what you want?

Comment: Include the msi provider.  I feel like I said that arleady.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart yes I want to enumarate all programs.

Comment: Please see my previous comment.